# Show that $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ has bounded variation iff exists $h:[0,1]\rightarrow [a,b]$ with $\gamma \circ h$ Lipschitz.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, lipschitz-functions, bounded-variation

Let $~\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}~$ be a continuous curve: show that $~\gamma~$ has bounded variation if and only if there exists $~h:[0,1]\rightarrow [a,b]~$ continuous and surjective such that $~\gamma \circ h~$ is a Lipschitz curve.

My only idea is for the proof of the reciprocal proposition: if $$
|\gamma(h(x))-\gamma(h(y))|\leq k|x-y|~\forall x,y\in [0,1],$$
then, given a partition $P=\{a=x_0,x_1,\dots, x_n=b\}$, I have that exists $~y_i~$ with $~h(y_i)=x_i~$ for each $i$ from $1$ to $n$. Then,
$$\sum_{i=1}^n|\gamma(x_i)-\gamma(x_{i-1})|\leq \sum_{i=1}^n|\gamma(h(y_i))-\gamma(h(y_{i-1}))|\leq k\sum_{i=1}^n|y_i-y_{i-1}|$$
But I don't know how to continue, because I think that $h$ is not necessarily monotonic.

Edit: For the direct implication I found a reference that helped me a lot, here goes https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253024/from-bounded-variation-to-1-lipschitz-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt works if $h$ is nondecreasing. I think my argument here shows that you can use $h$ to construct a nondecreasing function $g : [0,1] \to [a,b]$ such that $\gamma \circ g$ is also Lipschitz, after which you can apply your argument. (Please comment if you find errors in my argument.)

---

WLOG we may assume there exists $0 \le z_0 < z_1 \le 1$ such that $h(z_0)=a$ and $h(z_1)=b$. (If not, replace $h$ with $\tilde{h}(x)=h(1-x)$.)

Let $g:[z_0,1] \to [a,b]$ be defined by $g(x) = \sup_{t \in [z_0, x]} h(t)$. Show that $g$ is continuous, nondecreasing, and surjective onto $[a,b]$.

$\gamma$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$, so there exists $\delta$ such that $|u-u'| \le \delta$ implies $|\gamma(u)-\gamma(u')| \le \epsilon$.

I claim that for $z_0 \le x < y \le 1$, there exist $x',y'$ satisfying $x \le x' \le y' \le y$ such that
$h(x') = g(x)$ and $|g(y)-h(y')| \le \delta$.

> Proof of claim: If $g(y) > g(x)$, choose $y' \le y$ such that $|g(y) - h(y')| \le \min\{\delta, \frac{g(y)-g(x)}{2}\}$, by definition of $g(y)$. We must have $y' \ge x$ because $h(y') \ge g(y) - \frac{g(y)-g(x)}{2} =  \frac{g(y) + g(x)}{2} \ge g(x) = \sup_{[z_0, x]} h(t)$. Next, because $h(x) \le g(x) \le h(y')$, the intermediate value theorem implies the existence of some $x'$ between $x$ and $y'$ such that $h(x') = g(x)$.

By uniform continuity of $\gamma$, we have $$|\gamma(g(x)) - \gamma(g(y))| \le \epsilon + |\gamma(h(x'))-\gamma(h(y'))| \le \epsilon + k|x'-y'| \le \epsilon + k|x-y|.$$

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we see that $\gamma \circ g$ is also Lipschitz.

Finally, if we define the linear map $\tilde{g} : [0,1] \to [z_0, 1]$ by $\tilde{g}(t) = z_0 + t(1-z_0)$, you can note that $(g \circ \tilde{g}) : [0,1] \to [a,b]$ is your continuous nondecreasing surjection such that $\gamma \circ (g \circ \tilde{g})$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: Nice, I was trying to prove that g is surjective showing that is continuous, that's the way?
Another thing, shouldn't it be $x'\leq x \leq y'\leq y$ to use the deffinition of g?

Comment: Wait, the image of g is actually $[h(0),b]$, it's not necessarily that $h(0)=a$.

Comment: @vop Regarding $x \le x' \le y' \le y$, I've changed some things and added explanation. It is important that $x' \ge x$ so that we have the inequality $|x'-y'| \le |x - y|$ toward the end. Regarding the image of $g$, you were right, I had a mistake which I have now corrected.

Comment: @angryavian Why the image of $g$ is $[a,b]$?

Comment: @Chris Sorry, I fixed another mistake; please see my change in the definition of $g$. I've chosen $z_0$ so that $g(z_0)=a$. Also, $g(1) = \sup_{t \in [z_0, 1]} h(t) = b$. Finally, $g$ is continuous (because $h$ is).

Answer (score 2):

The intuition here: $\gamma$ has finite variation if and only if the curve $\gamma$ has finite length. Now the new parametrization is by arc-length, and it should be clear that it is Lipschitz with constant $1$. Works for maps into metric spaces $\gamma\colon [a,b] \to X$, continuous, and of finite variation.

Comment: $\int_a^b|\gamma '(t)|dt $ only makes sense when $\gamma$ is piecewise differentiable, but the parametrization is pretty similar to the arc-length.

Comment: @vop: Your idea is correct.  Functions of bounded variation do not need to be differentiable at all points. In fact, they can have values in metric spaces. If they take values in some $\mathbb{R}^n$  then they are differentiable almost everywhere. Still, the variation might not be the integral of $|\gamma'(t)|$, since it can have some singular component.